# Varchar charset=utf8 vs nvarchar

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, unicode

I've come across quite a few comparisons of `nvarchar` vs `varchar` and it usually always mentions the unicode vs non-unicode issue. However, in the case where a `varchar` column uses unicode charset/collation, such as with the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `t` 
(
    `title` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
    `studio` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
    `currency` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Does `nvarchar` and `varchar` mean the same thing, or are there still differences between them? Mysql or Postgres doesn't have this type, so I would assume that they become the same thing when the `varchar` is unicode?

Comment: On Microsoft SQL Server `nvarchar` effectively means UCS-2 encoding, i.e.: covers the Basic Multilingual Plane. That is unless the database is using a Supplementary Character collation (_SC) in which case it means UTF-16 encoding, i.e.: covers all Unicode code points. While it's possible to store UTF-16 data into `nvarchar` without an _SC collation, and plenty of applications do this, the SQL Server string functions will return incorrect results in the presence of supplementary characters, e.g.: `nchar(65536)` and above will return `null` instead of the desired Unicode code point.

Comment: You've tagged this for Oracle and SQL Server.  Your DDL appears to be for MySQL and you reference MySQL and PostgresSQL in your question.  Which database(s) are you actually intending to ask about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged "Oracle" I can give a statement for this.

In Oracle you have two character sets, the CHARACTER SET (for `VARCHAR2`, et. al.) and the NATIONAL CHARACTER SET (for `NVARCHAR2` et. al.)

They exist mainly for historical reasons. In earlier times the character set (e.g. `US7ASCII`) was intended for generic data, like PL/SQL code or meta data and the national character set (e.g. `WE8ISO8859P1` for Western Europe) for language specific data.

Nowadays the default character set is `AL32UTF8`, i.e. UTF-8 which covers entire Unicode. Actually I see no reason to use the national character set today. More and more new native Oracle functions do not support NVARCHAR2 data type, so today you should really avoid data types `NVARCHAR2`, `NCLOB`, etc.

Comment: I don't know why Oracle still offers two character sets, the db and the national; but there are meaningful differences between UTF-8 and UTF-16, and you may need to use both in the same db. (Even besides backward compatibility). UTF-8 uses less storage and is processed faster if most text is ASCII, but it uses more storage (and memory, when processed) and it is processed slower if most characters are Chinese characters, for example.